# Read zip file contents using ZipFile java class inside script

Tags: javascript, java, zip, servicenow

I have one requirement to read zip files content using a script. I wrote one script and tried to run it from my tool. I am using JAVA classes and it's giving the following error:

> Security restricted: Attempted access to restricted class name java.util.zip.ZipFile
>   Evaluator: java.lang.SecurityException: Illegal attempt to access class 'java.util.zip.ZipFile' via script
>   Caused by error in script at line 21

```
 var zFile = new Packages.java.io.File(x);
 gs.print(zFile);

 var reading = new Packages.java.util.zip.ZipFile(zFile);// Error here
 gs.print(reading);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had an issue similar but different.  Had to open a Hi ticket.

We used to use new Packages.java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream(); for zipping files.

We started getting these in Helsinki, but it worked in Fuji.  Service-now had to add these to the `sys_whitelist_package` and `sys_whitelist_member` list.

You could try opening up the ACL's on those tables to add the packages and member and see if that works.  Or you could open a HI ticket about why you need this package, and member.

Depending on where the zip file is, you could pass this off to a midserver to unzip it, then pass the individual files up.  It would be more complicated but you wouldn't have to get HI involved.